# jQuery AJAX data-toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Have a situation where I am using the jquery ".load()" method to load content into div's on my page using AJAX connections. At the moment at the end of the page I have to have a document.ready function and have to specify each and every single AJAX div manually with a load statement.

```html
<div id="div1">Loading...</div>
<div id="div2">Loading...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div1").load("path/to/file.php");
    $("#div2").load("path/to/file.php");
  });
</script>
```

Instead what I would like to do is work with the jQuery selector and the data- parameters in HTML5. I already use these for a number of other sections which are used to capture onclick events however having trouble with using the same technique for the AJAX load method.

What I currently have is...

```html
<div id="div1" data-toggle="pagelet" data-url="/path/to/file.php">Loading...</div>
<div id="div2" data-toggle="pagelet" data-url="/path/to/file2.php">Loading...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("[data-toggle='pagelet']").load($(this).data("url"));
  });
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. I know using the data-toggle and data-url paramaters work because when I resort to adding a click handler at first and embed the ajax load method on the click handler then it works when I click on the div's in question.

Can anyone give me an idea where I am going wrong and point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: you need to iterate and call load on each one, you can't do them all at once like you can when binding an event or setting a class... use each() then something like your hard-coded one inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through the result set as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("[data-toggle='pagelet']").each(function(){
        $(this).load($(this).data("url"));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Don, that fixed it all.

Comment: Glad I could help, please could you accept my answer, thanks.